# Why can't the VS 2015 compiler optimise a branch in an abs() implementation on float numbers?

Tags: c++, assembly, optimization

```
__declspec(dllexport)
float foo(float x) {
    return (x < 0) ? x * -1 : x;
}
```

This is a very naive implementation for calculating `abs(x)` where `x` is a `float`. I compiled this in Release mode and enabled all optimisations I could find. The resulting `asm` is:

```
; 4    :    return (x < 0) ? x * -1 : x;

    movss   xmm1, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
    xorps   xmm0, xmm0
    comiss  xmm0, xmm1
    jbe SHORT $LN3@foo
    xorps   xmm1, DWORD PTR __xmm@80000000800000008000000080000000
$LN3@foo:
    movss   DWORD PTR tv66[ebp], xmm1
    fld DWORD PTR tv66[ebp]
```

As you can see this still contains the branch and the conditional jump. Yet a `float` is defined by the IEEE754 and thus I could change the implementation to simply set the sign bit to 0:

```
__declspec(dllexport)
float foo(float x) {
    void* bar = &x;
    __int32 y = ((*(__int32*)bar) & ~(1 << 31));
    return  *(float*)&y;
}
```

which does not jump and requires less commands:

```
; 3    :        void* bar = &x;
; 4    :        __int32 y = ((*(__int32*)bar) & ~(1 << 31));

    mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[ebp]
    and eax, 2147483647             ; 7fffffffH
    mov DWORD PTR _y$[ebp], eax

; 5    :        return  *(float*)&y;

    fld DWORD PTR _y$[ebp]
```

I would have expected that there even exist specific commands for this action, but maybe this is only on very special architectures?

So what is the reason the compiler can't catch this optimization? Or am I making a mistake by doing this?

Comment: Did you test it with the obvious corner cases?  NaN, INF, -INF, denorms, max, min, epsilon?  Prove and test that is.

Comment: @Yakk What do you mean with epsilon? I only know that for machine precision and I am not sure how this could interfere with me setting the sign bit to 0.

Comment: Consider using the `copysign` function instead.

Comment: @firefoz I am just listing a pile of somewhat special floating point values.  There are lots, and some are quirky.  Testing them *and* checking their ieee mandated bit patterns seems like a first step here.  I am no floating point expert.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because that would yield the wrong result for negative zero!

Negative zero is not smaller than zero, so its sign stays negative, rendering an elimination of the conditional branch invalid.

Consider using something like

```
copysign(x, 0.0);
```

instead.

Comment: Bah I misses `-0` from my list of quirky floats.  Bad yakk no cookie.